# Laravel 5 Migration namespace

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

Hello I'm new to Laravel coming from Codeigniter

I try to start building my database from migration but I see some script in Github use  namespace in deferent ways like :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

another script use :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
```

and another use only :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```

on start of class why they use namespace in these ways ?

my code here  what I use and why ??

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Test extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('test');
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest reading the PHP docs about namespaces in order to understand the concept behind namespaces in general: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php Note that Laravel uses the autoloader provided by composer in order to autoload classes based on namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Schema` facade has an alias registered in `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    ...
]
```

Since the migration class resides in the global namespace, the same namespace as the `Schema` alias, so having the `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` is redundant because it does the same thing as the alias registration.

So you **do not need** to include that `use` statement in your migration class files. Having:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
```

will be enough.

---

As for the ones that include only `use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;` they probably don't type hint the closure parameter.

So if you have this:

```
public function up()
{
    // Notice the 'Blueprint $table' type hint
    Schema::create('test',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

you need to include `use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;`. But if you have this:

```
public function up()
{
    // Notice NO type hint for the '$table' closure parameter
    Schema::create('test',function($table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

You don't need to include `use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;`.

---

The `use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;` is always necessary because the migration class extends it:

```
class Test extends Migration
```

Comment: thank you  ,  its mean too  can I add this name space to aliases and use it direct from controller

Comment: Yes, you can include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` and then use `Schema::create(...)` in your controller. Or you can have just `\Schema::create(...)` without the `use` statement, because the "\" in front of the class name means if will be resolved in the global namespace.